# how to retain the value of the last iteration on a sequence in for-in

Tags: swift, swift2, for-in-loop

```
var index: Int=0
for index in 1...3{
    print(index)
}
print(index)//prints 0
```

If I run this code, the last print gives 0, which means the index inside the for-in is not the same as outside. Seems like this force declares a new constant.
I am looking for similar way to retain the last value in the sequence

I know I can do

```
var index_out: Int=0
for index in 1...3{
    print(index)
    index_out = index
}
print(index_out)
```

Comment: Maybe your example is too simple. You  already know the value of index_out before the loop. Why do you want to compute it?

Answer (score 2):

If you're gonna loop through something and want to know the end index just use the amount of times you looped through it:

```
let n = 3
for index in 1...n{
    print(index)
}
print(n)
```

Or with an array:

```
let array = [Int](count: 10, repeatedValue: 2)

for index in 0..<array.count {
    print(index)
}

print(array.count)
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you know you can do it is how to do it, for loops create their own scope. Anything declared inside of a set of { } means that it's for use within that scope only.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the way `for in` is implemented with an outer scope generator and while:

```
var generator = sequence.generate()
var element = generator.next()
while let x = generator.next() {
    element = x
}
// element is nil if the sequence is empty
print(element)
```

this is only another way to do this but personally I think you should avoid that.

A much nicer solution would be with reduce (in Swift 1.x: global function, in Swift 2: as method)

```
// with default value
let lastElement = sequence.reduce(default) { $1 }

// if default should be nil you have to provide the explicit type because it cannot be inferred; probably use an extension:
// as extension
extension SequenceType {
    var last: Self.Generator.Element? {
        return self.reduce(nil) { $1 }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it, since it is in different scope than your method. But you also SHOULD NOT do what you do, to assign to your index on each iteration - that is wasteful. Instead, just increase index after you are done:

```
var data = []
var lastIndex = 0
for (index, object) in enumerate(data) {
    ...
}

lastIndex += data.count
```

Or, if you need to break for cycle for some reason, just assign it from inside of the cycle just before you break.

Comment: the index is not necessarily an Int or not necessarily in an order I know before hand...

Comment: Sure. But that is what my post says - you will always use last value before break or last value of entire array (or whatever). You can use += for index, you can use array.last, you can use array[someIndexBeforeBreak] just before break. There is just no need to assign it every time. Or if you think there is, can you provide example?

Comment: ahh...no, I do not want this assignment, that is true. In other languages I would simply access the `index` outside the loop (Which actually works in swift with simple `for` loops). Was trying to figure out if this is also possible with `for...in` loops exactly to avoid the need to compute/assign etc.